# Weird addition in React

Tags: reactjs

There is an input, and i want value from that input to be added to current state variable, which is integer and initially 0, but it adds like a string. 
If i put in the input number 50, state adds up to 050, not 0+50 = 50, as you'd expect.

My code :

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { degreesToRadiansFlipped } from "./helpers/degreesToRadiansFlipped";
function Circle() {
  let [degree, setDegree] = useState(0);
  const inputField = useRef();


  return (
    <div>
      <canvas width={500} height={500}></canvas>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setDegree((degree += inputField.current.value));
          console.log(inputField.current.value);
        }}
      >
        <input type="number" ref={inputField}></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Circle;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input's `value` property is always a `string`, just convert it to an `int` before the operation

```
degree += parseInt(inputField.current.value)
```